# Split and VBA.Split

Tags: vba, split

Playing with excel and came up with this error

```
    Sub Split()

Dim txt As String
Dim x As Variant
txt = Sheets("Raw").Cells(2, 2).Value
MsgBox (txt)
x = Split(txt, ",")
For Each i In x
MsgBox (i)
Next
```

Give me an error of two many arguments for the split function

however

```
    Sub Split()

Dim txt As String
Dim x As Variant
txt = Sheets("Raw").Cells(2, 2).Value
MsgBox (txt)
x = VBA.Split(txt, ",")
For Each i In x
MsgBox (i)
Next
```

works just fine?

So whats going on, I am sure i have used split before with out needing the vba. prefix?

Cheers

Aaron

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not real familiar with Excel VBA, but looking at the code snippet you posted I think the VBA interpreter may have gotten confused.

You have `Sub Split()`, and the code that follows is, I assume, for that function?

When it tried to execute `Split(txt, ",")`, it most likely thought you were referring to your Split function, which takes no arguments, yet you were passing in two.

Using `VBA.Split` resolved the reference confusion, because you're then telling it to use the Split method in the VBA namespace.

Comment: Dohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!! Talk about feeling a fool now!! ;) You know that might just be it... :)

Comment: +1 this is the answer all right. Never name udf and sub with existing function names - its incredibly confusing for users as well :)

Comment: I was just wanting to test a short bit of code, which is why the silly subname. Doh, Doh and Doh again. :)

Comment: Watch out for modules named with sub or function names as well.

Comment: To add to what every one else has already identified, when you wrote VBA.Split **you qualified your reference so it wasn't ambiguous**. For the same reason "Application" can be ambiguous but Outlook.Application and Excel.Application aren't.